# SQL Date Conditions

Tags: sql, date, datetime, conditional-statements

How do I create a Date condition for the user to add Date after a specific time by adding a limit to the Date value?

Example:

I need to create a `Hire_Date` that only requires the user to enter a date after than 01/12/1980.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You should add the code you have try until here, show what documentation you read (that could lead us to the database you are using). Without that, no good answer will be provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `check` constraint:

```
alter table t
    add constraint chk_t_hiredate check (hiredate > date '1980-12-01');
```

Note that the `date` keyword is not needed (or allowed) in some databases.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you.

I completely forgot about that "Check" command.